# Meaning of 'Edwardian geek'

Tags: expressions

I just read that a physicist Paul Dirac was called 'the Edwardian geek' by his biographer [See the quote below from Wiki]. What does this phrase mean (Who was that particular Edward)?

> An anecdote recounted in a review of the 2009 biography tells of Werner 
>   Heisenberg and Dirac sailing on a cruise ship to a conference in Japan in 
>   August 1929. "Both still in their twenties, and unmarried,
>   they made an odd couple. Heisenberg was a ladies' man who constantly
>   flirted and danced, while Dirac—'an Edwardian geek', as biographer
>   Graham Farmelo puts it—suffered agonies if forced into any kind of
>   socialising or small talk. 'Why do you dance?' Dirac asked his
>   companion. 'When there are nice girls, it is a pleasure,' Heisenberg
>   replied. Dirac pondered this notion, then blurted out: 'But,
>   Heisenberg, how do you know beforehand that the girls are nice?'"

Comment: A geek of the Edwardian period, I'm guessing?

Comment: The Edward in question is King Edward VII (reg. 1901-1910)

Comment: This is General Reference. [Edwardian](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Edwardian) - *of or pertaining to the reign of Edward VII*, [geek]() - *a computer expert or enthusiast*, or *a peculiar or otherwise dislikable person, especially one who is perceived to be overly intellectual*. It's in quotes because the word probably didn't exist in Edwardian times (computer geeks as we know them today certainly didn't exist then).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is not easily accessible to non-English speakers.

Comment: @ Dilawar: That may well be so - but so far as I'm concerned, such questions belong on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Which is only in "beta mode" at the moment, so I can't propose migrating this Q in my closevote, but I don't see this as a suitable issue for [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq), as per the **ELU** FAQ.

Comment: I would like to quote another such instance from a book which might make it clear "By every account of Dirac's behaviour in his mid-teens, he had the same personality characteristics as today's pasty-faced technofiles who prefer using the latest software and gadgets to mixing with other people and who are happiest sitting alone at their computer screens. From a modern perspective, the young Dirac was an Edwardian geek"

Answer (score 1):

In this case 'Edward' could refer to Edward VII (Albert Edward; 9 November 1841 – 6 May 1910), who was King of the United Kingdom.

The First World War was approaching. Edward involved himself heavily in discussions over army reform. He supported the re-design of army command, the creation of the Territorial Force, and the decision to provide an Expeditionary Force supporting France in the event of war with Germany.

Paul Dirac could have been a supporter of King Edward VII.

Comment: He *could* have been; but 'Edwardian' and 'Victorian' are often used to describe houses and furniture, so usually refer to the period not the politics.

Comment: It wasn't meant in that sense. He spent his mid teens like someone we call a geek. So referring to that period, an *Edwardian geek*.